# Windows 10 - Chrome 'pinch and zoom' without touch screen?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, zoom

I have a Surface Book 2 laptop and also a desktop. I find it easier to read when I zoom in on articles and emails. If I use 'ctrl and +' to zoom in, unfortunately, it also makes all the panes and sidebars on the website larger as well. But if I pinch and zoom, I can get the text to fill the physical screen - it works a lot better for zooming in to read. Is there any way I can simulate 'pinch and zoom' on my desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension, that makes your zoom work as a laptop trackpad:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mouse-pinch-to-zoom/pffiadlahfhoniddbipeiiohjnlongfi

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I have been looking for it :( The closer you can go it to do Win + / Win - which activates the magnifier which does not change layoutt but of course it is not the same.